# Observable takeUntil confusion

Tags: angular, observable

I came across this answer [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription/41177163#41177163) on how to stop a subscription using takeUntil(). The answer also states that

> The secret sauce (as noted already by @metamaker) is to call .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe) before each of our .subscribe() calls which will guarantee all subscriptions will be cleaned up when the component is destroyed.

I am however having problems understanding why one of my two examples does not stop the subscription. [Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/takeuntil-example)

My Service:

```
export class GpsService {
  gps: Observable<any>;
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() { }
  startFakeGps = (): void => {
    // This example does not stop the subscription after calling stopGps().
    this.gps = Observable.timer(3000, 1000);
    this.gps.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe);

    // This example stops the subscription after calling stopGps().
    // this.gps = Observable.timer(3000, 1000).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe);
  }

  stopGps() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
}
```

My component:

```
export class ButtonOverviewExample implements OnInit {

  constructor(private gspService: GpsService){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.gspService.startFakeGps();
    this.gspService.gps.subscribe(data => {});
  }

  // stop gps after clicking a button 
  stopGps(){
    this.gspService.stopGps();
  }


}
```

**Example 1:**

```
    // This example does not stop the subscription after calling stopGps().
    this.gps = Observable.timer(3000, 1000);
    this.gps.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe);
```

**Example 2:**

```
    // This example stops the subscription after calling stopGps().
    this.gps = Observable.timer(3000, 1000).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe);
```

I thought that both examples are using `takeUntil()` before the actual subscription starts, and that they are the same. Why is it different behaviour on these examples? What am I missing?

[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/takeuntil-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.gps = Observable.timer(3000, 1000);
```

create observable and save it in `this.gps`

```
this.gps.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe);
```

create NEW observable, but `this.gps` is not change
You need to combine creating observable and adding `.takeUntil` operator

```
this.gps = Observable.timer(3000, 1000).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe);
```

Comment: Exactly, the rxjs operators don't mutate the underlying Observable, they create a new one that you have to store. So alternatively (but not great style) this would work: `this.gps = this.gps.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After understanding that it creates a new observable, everything makes sense.

Comment: Be carefull, sometimes you must use flat arrow Observable.takeUntil(() => this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe()